# Specification Testing with EF - The ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, specflow, xunit

I have the following SpecFlow scenario:

```
[When(@"the registration is submitted")]
public void WhenTheRegistrationIsSubmitted()
{
    //var controller = _kernel.Get<AccountController>();

    var factory = new HockeyDbContextFactory();

    var userRepository = new Repository<User>(factory);
    var cryptoService = new CryptoService();
    var roleRepository = new Repository<Role>(factory);
    var playerService = new Mock<IPlayerService>();
    var leagueService = new Mock<ILeagueService>();
    var userService = new UserService(userRepository, cryptoService, roleRepository);
    var controller = new AccountController(userService, playerService.Object, leagueService.Object);

    controller.Register(_registerModel);
}
```

Which eventually calls the following method through my controller:

```
public void RegisterUser(User user)
{
    var salt = _cryptoService.GenerateSalt();
    var hasedPassword = _cryptoService.HashPassword(user.Password, salt);

    user.PasswordSalt = salt;
    user.Password = hasedPassword;

    var defaultRole = _roleRepository.GetAll().Single(x => x.RoleName == "User");
    user.Roles.Add(defaultRole);

    Insert(user);
}
```

All of my database calls are fine until I get to this line:

`var defaultRole = _roleRepository.GetAll().Single(x => x.RoleName == "User");`

When I breakpoint on that line and inspect the call to GetAll(), I have context and I can view the query. The exception occurs on the call to Single(). Now, if I stick a `.Include(x => x.Users)` on the call to GetAll(), I'm fine. This tells me it has something to do with lazy-loading.

The error i get is: *error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.*

When RegisterUser is called from my web application, I'm fine. When RegisterUser is called from my specification test, it fails. Does anyone have some incite?

**UPDATE:**

To add a little more information, here is the controller action being called:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (!_userService.EmailIsUnique(model.EmailAddress))
        ModelState.AddModelError("EmailAddress", "Email Address is already in use.");

    if (!_userService.UserNameIsUnique(model.UserName))
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User Name is already in use");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {

            var user = Mapper.Map<User>(model);
            _userService.RegisterUser(user);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

            return View("RegisterSuccess");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

stepping through the code, I never make it to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);`

Comment: This means that in your SpecFlow scenario `role.Users` is accessed, triggering lazy loading while the context is gone. Hard to tell for an outsider where this could happen.

Comment: I added an update to show the controller action, but my SpecFlow scenario isn't doing anything else. I've ripped out DI and simplified the problem as much as I can. I do have a Given that sets up _registerModel, but that's just setting some static data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. I was seeding my test database with this step:

```
[BeforeFeature]
public static void BeforeFeature()
{
    MappingConfig.RegisterMappings();
    Database.SetInitializer(new TestDatabaseInitializer());
}
```

The context in my TestDatabaseInitializer must have been conflicting with the context I created in my scenario. Thanks for the comment Gert, it gave me the idea to take a closer look at what was going on in the rest of my scenario.