# ObjectContext has been disposed throwed by EnsureConnection() in consecutive queries (No navigation properties used and no using())

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Somehow EF disposes the ObjectContext in between two queries, without any further notice, but apparently not randomly and not due to a timeout.

*I added the using so the example is self contained but it does the same with the DbContext used in the whole application.*

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  //I am sure these are unique
  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane");
  Node node = db.Nodes.Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff"); //Here the request throws
  // "ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"
}
```

Notice `db` is not yet disposed by using so this is out of the question.
The error also happens with `.First()` and `.Where().Single/First()`.

Inverting the two requests does not do the trick:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  Node node = db.Nodes.Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff");
  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane"); //Here the request throws
  // "ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"
}
```

I do not use any navigation propery of Employee either, and this does not solve the problem:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  // According to every post I've found this "should fix the objectcontext disposed error"
  db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane");
  Node node = db.Nodes.Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff"); //But it doesn't: same error here
}
```

What I have noted is this problem doesn't occur on the WebSite project but only in the UnitTests project. I have set the same connectionString for the two (apart from the db name) but that didn't do anything either.

Worse yet :

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  Node node = db.Nodes.Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff");
  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane"); // boom
  node.Should().NotBeNull();
}

using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  Node node = db.Nodes.Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff");
  node.Should().NotBeNull();
  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane"); // no boom
}
```

The timeout is set to 20000 and `MultipleActiveResultSets` is set to `true`.

For now the only workaround I found was to call `.ToList()` on the whole DbSet before trying `.Single()`:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
{
  Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(e => e.FirstName == "Bob" && e.LastName == "Morane");
  Node node = db.Nodes.ToList().Single(n => n.ShortName == "stuff"); //Works
}
```

But **this isn't acceptable** because the operation is frequent and I expect the DbSet to be quite big so this will take a lot of time for nothing.

Comment: What test framework are you using? Does the test runner support multithreading? If so, try turning this off.

Comment: This is not an anwser, but UnitTests are not supposed to hit a database.

Comment: The test framework is NUnit 2.6.2

Comment: Have a look at the "Worse yet" part. This is really puzzling :(

Comment: Can you override `Dispose` in `MyDbContext`, add a breakpoint inside the override, and look at the stack trace when Dispose is called? That might give you a clue about what is causing the problem.

Comment: Apparently, when the first request is made, the DbContext fills the Database with seeded data, this produces a call to a method in a Model class using a `using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())` that disposes of an instance of MyDbContext. The instance created in the using I wrote up there in my code does not seem to be disposed, but if the connection is shared somehow this might kill it. I am then looking for a way to remove that dumb `using` in the Model.

Comment: Well no ... commenting the whole `using` block inside that other method does not change the error and the breakpoint in MyDbContext.Dispose() is never triggered...

Comment: So no answers... not even an upvote :(

Comment: If you can't see anything from the client, look at what the server says; maybe it's the latter that's dropping the connection for some reason. Look at logs, and profile the queries, you might get a clue there. If not, at least you'll be able to confirm that the framework is deliberately closing it.

Comment: Apparently the DbContext is disposing of ObjectContext, for some reason, but `DbContext.Dispose` is not called, so it's not from there... What server are you talking about? The Sql server?

Comment: The ObjectContext is disposed, I don't know from where, but the method in DbContext containing a call to ObjectContext.Dispose() is never called. The ObjectContext is disposed, sets its connection to `null` and then a subsequent use of this ObjectContext throws the exception.

Comment: Which EF version are you using?

Comment: We are using EF v5.00

Comment: http://jupaol.blogspot.com/2012/10/entityframework-context-per-request.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033303/specification-testing-with-ef-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed

Comment: @m4ngl3r thank you, the first one is not it because there is no notion of request here, but the second one looks interesting, though it's not detailed enough: How does the TestInitializer affects the context? What should we do about it?

Comment: what does your DbContext constructor link like ?

Comment: @m4ngl3r apparently it was indeed the TestInitializer() that was conflicting somehow with the other context. Skimming through EF source code it seems to do some obscure duplications and proxying of the context before sending it to the initializer. I removed the SetInitializer and replaced it by `context.Database.Delete(); context.Database.Create(); Seeder.seed(context);`

Comment: so, is it ok now ? you get the same error or anything else?

Comment: The exception is gone, I don't really know what was wrong precisely, but it's gone. The TestInitializer was inheriting `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>` and just implemented `Seed(MyDbcontext context) { Seeder.seed(context); }`

Comment: well, i guess that was this initializer which was doing some tricky stuff with your context, glad you've fixed it =]

Comment: Thanks, me too. It was EF that was doing tricky stuff to the context before sending it to the initializer, and then messing up the management thereafter :S...

Comment: @m4ngl3r if you want to anser the question and get the bounty, go on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as we (with more effort by Eregrith) found out, it was the EF which was doing manipulations with context before sending it to test initializer so that it was functioning unexpectedly ; by implementing basic create/seed/delete instead of initializer the exception was gone.
(in my opinion, it still needs more detailed investigation of what actually happens there =] )

The test initializer was called like this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DatabaseTestInitializer());
```

DatabaseTestInitializer:

```
public class DatabaseTestInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        SeederHelper.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Removing the call to SetInitializer<> solved the problem.

In base class UnitTest:

```
[SetUp]
protected virtual void Initialize()
{

  ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  this.RegisterTypes(builder);
  this.Container = builder.Build();

  //Removed: System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DatabaseTestInitializer());
  this.Db = Container.Resolve<MyDbContext>();
  this.Db.Should().NotBeNull();

  //Below: code added
  this.Db.Database.Delete();
  this.Db.Database.Create();
  SeederHelper.Seed(this.Db);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion this is what got me there.

Comment: i'm glad you've managed to figure it out yourself after that suggestion =]

Comment: Well your link had the answer saying it was the initializer, I removed it and voilà ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Nunit but I did have a similar issue a while back with multiple mstests interfering.

Try turning off connection pooling within the connection string via **Pooling=false**

But only for the unit test project

Comment: This did not change anything. And the test fails only when launched alone as before.

Comment: Its also important that you specify that your lists are virtual such as public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; internal set; }

Comment: First `Employees` is not a navigation property, it is a `DbSet<Employee>`, second there is no lazyloading directly involved as I mentionned: the two queries call upon objects with no navigation property in common and no navigation property is ever used in the lambda or implicitly.